# Can PostgreSQL in Heroku change the order of a .all() query from Django's ORM?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, orm

I have a method that extracts the medications from a prescription and makes it into a JSON list. (There is a ForeignKey relation between medications and prescriptions).

Somehow, the order of the medication JSON list is reversed in the production server in Heroku (Python-Django, Cedar stack). I can solve it with the last command `[::-1]` to reverse the list, but I really want to understand why this happens, and if it is the `.all()` query or the `for` somehow.

```
# I call the function with this query
medications = get_medication_json(prescription.medications.all())


# Get json of medications as an array, it's used to display in email body and pdf and views
def get_medication_json(medications):
    medication_json = []
    for medication in medications:
        json = {}
        json['instructions'] = medication.instructions
        # Only if there's a drug
        if medication.drug:
            json['id'] = medication.drug.id
            json['name'] = medication.drug.name+' ('+medication.drug.formula+')'
        # Only if there's a presentation
        if medication.presentation:
            json['presentation'] = medication.presentation
        medication_json.append(json)
    return medication_json[::-1]
```

Comment: What do mean by `reversed`? What is normal ordering of `medications` and what ordering do you get?

Comment: There is no default ordering, but the outcome is reversed. That is, if in the development environment I get `[1,2,3]` I get `[3,2,1]` on my production server.

Comment: @VladimirDanilov Reading up on Postgres documentation, they recommend explicitly designating a particular output order. They say `The actual order in that case will depend on the scan and join plan types and the order on disk` but I still would not understand why this is different on my production server.

Comment: Because it will depend on the order they were inserted, and other transient conditions of the database. Define a default ordering in the model, or use an `order_by` clause in the query.

Comment: @DanielRoseman They are inserted systematically in the same order by an inline form.

Comment: Although, granted, defining a default order or ordering the query would also solve the problem.